# how do you store a csv or JSON file to hive using apache NiFi?

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-nifi

I have noticed that there is no processor available in nifi that can directly store the file into hive. is there any combination of processors that can help with this or are there any templates available that can do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the next version of NiFi (0.7.0) there will be some initial processors for interacting with Hive. One of them will be PutHiveQL which can take a flow file with a Hive QL statement as the content and execute it using the hive JDBC driver.

The likely flow for csv or json would be to first parse the data into the values needed to construct an insert statement, probably using ExtractText or EvaluateJsonPath, and then use ReplaceText and expressions language to construct the insert statement.

The other common approach without having the Hive processors is to use the PutHDFS processor to store data to a directory in HDFS, and then create an external Hive table on top of that.

Comment: hey Bryan, i have looked into the release notes for the version 0.7.0 and don`t see any new processors for hive. here is the link i am referring to https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NIFI/Release+Notes#ReleaseNotes-Version0.7.0